# merge DataFrames with multiple keys and one key being column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and I want to merge them using 2 keys and one of them will be columns directly

I have the following Dataframes:

DF:-

```
    Sex Age    Height   country    Year   Grade
0   M   31.0    188.0   Bulgaria    2016    D+
1   F   28.0    166.0   China       1996    D+
2   M   30.0    NaN     Sweden      1960    D+
3   F   28.0    181.0   China       2004    D+
4   F   16.0    175.0   Hungary     1998    D+
```

GDP_data:

```
    Country Name    Country Code    2016       1996     1960     2004      1998
0   Bulgaria          BGR           1946      NaN       5377    5285       NaN
1   China             CHI           1186      3314      NaN     7314       3314
2   Sweden            SWE           1590      4694      2723    8532       4694
3   China             CHI           6580      NaN       NaN     5120       NaN
4   Hungary           HUN           2858      1223      NaN     2935       1223
```

The desired Dataframe after merge is:-

```
    Sex Age    Height   country    Year   Grade   GDP
0   M   31.0    188.0   Bulgaria    2016    D+    1946
1   F   28.0    166.0   China       1996    D+    3314
2   M   30.0    NaN     Sweden      1960    D+    2723
3   F   28.0    181.0   China       2004    D+    5120
4   F   16.0    175.0   Hungary     1998    D+    1223
```

The resultant DataFrame should get the GDP of country with respect to year.

I need to match Country Name and country from DF and GDP_data respectively and also Year column from first DataFrame but in the second DataFrame I have years as columns.

How do I merge these two?

This is just the sample Data I have shown here but in reality it is very big data with arount 20000 rows and gdp data from 1960 to 2016. But the Idea should be the same.

Comment: How did you end up with 2 same columns `1996`?

Comment: That is a mistake I will edit it

Comment: Google for `melt` function

Comment: In GDP data dataframe, you have 2 rows of China as Country Name and Year as 2004, which one should be picked? there are a lot of grey areas in this question, please review and edit your question

Comment: Out of those 2 entries one is for GDP of china for the year 1996 and another is for year 2004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have named these DataFrames `a` and `b`, respectively. I also added an underscore in the names of columns where there is a space.

`b` needs to be melted.

```py
>>> melted = b.melt(id_vars=('Country_Name', 'Country_Code'), var_name='year', value_name='GDP')
   Country_Name Country_Code  year     GDP
0      Bulgaria          BGR  2016  1946.0
1         China          CHI  2016  1186.0
2        Sweden          SWE  2016  1590.0
3         China          CHI  2016  6580.0
...
```

And this continues. You can then merge the two DataFrames.

```py
>>> pd.merge(a, melted, left_on=('country', 'Year'), right_on=('Country_Name', 'year'))
  Sex   Age  Height   country  Year Grade Country_Name Country_Code  year     GDP
0   M  31.0   188.0  Bulgaria  2016    D+     Bulgaria          BGR  2016  1946.0
1   F  28.0   166.0     China  1996    D+        China          CHI  1996  3314.0
2   F  28.0   166.0     China  1996    D+        China          CHI  1996     NaN
3   M  30.0     NaN    Sweden  1960    D+       Sweden          SWE  1960  2723.0
4   F  28.0   181.0     China  2004    D+        China          CHI  2004  7314.0
5   F  28.0   181.0     China  2004    D+        China          CHI  2004  5120.0
6   F  16.0   175.0   Hungary  1998    D+      Hungary          HUN  1998  1223.0
```

The redundant columns can be dropped.

Update: I see that there are sometimes more than one GDP for a given country and year, so one possibility is to retain only the highest.

```py
>>> new_melted = melted.sort_values('GDP', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(('Country_Name', 'year'))

   Country_Name Country_Code  year     GDP
17       Sweden          SWE  2004  8532.0
16        China          CHI  2004  7314.0
3         China          CHI  2016  6580.0
10     Bulgaria          BGR  1960  5377.0
...
14      Hungary          HUN  1960     NaN
20     Bulgaria          BGR  1998     NaN
```

You can then perform the same merge with this one.

Comment: I was too slow, damn phone ;) +1

Comment: Wow this is what I was exactly looking for. Thanks a lot